# DatatypeExpr cannot be cast to BoolExpr in Z3 Java Api when using Enums

Tags: enums, z3, solver

I am new to enums in Z3. I actually just looked at an example and tried to reproduce it in a simplified way:

```
Context ctx = new Context();  
Solver myZ3 = myContext.mkSolver();
Symbol symbolUnderTest = myContext.mkSymbol("Tomato");
EnumSort FruitEnum = myContext.mkEnumSort(myContext.mkSymbol("FruitEnum"), myContext.mkSymbol("Apple"), myContext.mkSymbol("Orange")); 
Expr myConstraint = myContext.mkConst("fruityExpr", FruitEnum);
z3Solver.add(myConstraint); // <-- exception happens here.
// now i would like to check, whether "Tomato" is part of the "FruitEnum"
z3Solver.check();
```

Later I would like to query the solver whether a certain item is part of the enumeration "enumSort" or not.
But when i already try to add the enum declaration to the solver i get a casting error. I was trying to find the answer to this problem myself but so far i was not successfull. Does anyone know, what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Please post a minimum but complete example, not just code fragments.

Comment: i changed the example

Comment: That's still not a "full" example. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You're receiving this error because `myConstraint`, as you defined, is not a constraint. The statement:

```java
Expr myConstraint = myContext.mkConst("fruityExpr", enumSort);
```

makes the variable `myConstraint` stand for a symbolic `fruityExpr`; i.e., it's either an `Apple` or an `Orange`, but you're not putting any further constraints on it.

A constraint, however, is a boolean value. That is, it states some fact about an object. This is the error you're getting: z3 is telling you that a fruit object by itself isn't a constraint that you can `add` to the collection of facts. It needs to be of boolean type. This is the meaning of the error `DataTypeExpr` cannot be a `BoolExpr`. (The latter is the type of expressions that can be made into constraints, i.e., booleans.)

### Checking if something is a `fruit`

Note that SMTLib is a "typed" language. That is, every object has an associated type. (See section 2.2 of http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/papers/smt-lib-reference-v2.6-r2021-05-12.pdf; where it uses the term *sort* and *type* synonymously.) What this means is that you can't really create a symbol of type `fruit` that's not already a fruit. (This is like asking if `2` is a number or not. By its very definition it's a number.) This is similar to programming in statically-typed languages like Haskell, ML, etc., as opposed to dynamically typed languages like Python, Lisp etc. For the former, types really are prescriptive and thus they avoid a ton of programming errors. SMTLib has the same approach to how models are written, which is really helpful when building bigger models.

### Exploring z3

If you're new to z3, I recommend going through some basic tutorials first. Also, unless you have some other reason, Java isn't really a good host-language to explore z3 with. It's too low level and you'll get lost in the details for a learning project. (It can be a good choice when you integrate with other projects that are written in Java, but it's not a good first choice here.) I recommend use the Python variant, and go through this tutorial: https://ericpony.github.io/z3py-tutorial/guide-examples.htm It provides a good overview, and has a section on enumerations in https://ericpony.github.io/z3py-tutorial/advanced-examples.htm. While the tutorial is written using Python as the carrier language, the ideas apply to all other host languages, including Java.

Comment: hi @alias, thanks for your quick reply. I changed the example to be complete. Also you are completly right: "myConstraint" is not a constraint. How do i though create a constraint based on this, where i ask whether a certain item is included in an enum or not?