# Creating constraints over EnumSorts in Z3 Java api

Tags: java, z3, smt

i am stuck and need some help from you (i consulted the documentation and looked at the master example in Z3 github repo but could not find an example for what i want to do).

Lets say i would like to have an enum, that contains all the RGB (i.e. red, green, blue) colors and I would like to pose constraint on this enum, whether any particular color is contained by the enum or not.

The following constraint should evaluate to Sat: *enumRgb **contains** "red" && enumRgb **contain** "green"*

This constraint should evaluate to UnSat: *enumRgb **contains** "pink".*

In code (its not complete, because I am stuck) it looks like this:

```
public Expr addEnumExpr() { 
  EnumSort rgbEnum = myCtx.mkEnumSort(myCtx.mkSymbol("rgbEnum"), myCtx.mkSymbol("red"), myCtx.mkSymbol("green"), myCtx.mkSymbol("blue")); 
  Symbol colorPink = myCtx.mkSymbol("pink"); 
  Expr enumExpr = myCtx.mkConst("enumExpr", rgbEnum); 
  return myCtx.mkEq(colorPink, enumExpr); 
}
```

Note: myCtx is a global variable that holds the Context.

So the concrete problems I am having:

1. the equals constraint cannot be create because of incompatible types (colorPink is a Symbol)
2. Is the equals expression even the right one, in order to check for containment of a certain color in the enum?

Comment: You already asked this question and got an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70157458/datatypeexpr-cannot-be-cast-to-boolexpr-in-z3-java-api-when-using-enums

Comment: No. It was not. I asked how to create a specific constraint over an enumeration. A simple example would actually be more helpful

Comment: SMTLib is a typed language. This means that you cannot create any value of your enum that has the value `pink`. This is like asking if `"hello"`  is a number. In a typed system, that will never happen.

Comment: Thanks. That answer actually helped me. Sorry if my original question was stupid or something

Comment: No worries. When you're given an answer and you don't accept/vote on it, it's hard to tell if you've further questions or if something else was confusing. This is how stack-overflow works in general. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

See the [Z3Py tutorial](https://ericpony.github.io/z3py-tutorial/advanced-examples.htm), search for "Color" :-)

Note that you should not be able to create an expression of sort `rgbEnum` for "pink", because the result would clearly not be an expression of sort `rgbEnum`.  You can however create a constant/variable of sort `rgbEnum` which has the name "pink", e.g. `Expr pink = myCtx.mkConst("pink", rgbEnum);`, but that constant will never be assigned any value that's not in the enum.

Comment: The way I understand it then is that if I have a set of values (i.e. the enum rgbColor) and I want to test other random values (i.e. other colors, such as "pink") whether they are part of this set then enumSort is not necessary the write type to do so, because i cannot just ask an enum whether a certain symbol (e.g "pink") is part of it or not. Did i understand it correctly? Also thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You need a type/sort that contains all colours before you can make statements about subsets of them.